# What is 150 degree test kerosene?

Tags: hydrocarbons

I saw an old ad for kerosene in which it was advertised at "150 degree test".

What does that mean?

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for, page 282 if it doesn't go automatically. https://books.google.com/books?id=3wQSAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq=150+degree+fire+test+kerosene&source=bl&ots=jkpt6yW-J1&sig=229KLWed3sgTOS6dJSskNWzb0FE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjryKPPjIDZAhWl5IMKHXmQA3QQ6AEITDAK#v=onepage&q=150%20degree%20fire%20test%20kerosene&f=false